# magento 2 : reindex display Unknown 503 error from Elasticsearch null

Tags: magento2

when i reindex this errore show

> Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
> Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
> Unknown 503 error from Elasticsearch null

test elasticsearch

> [neil@194-31-194-14 www]$ curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/
> {
> "name" : "194-31-194-14.cprapid.com",
> "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
> "cluster_uuid" : "*na*",
> "version" : {
> "number" : "7.17.1",
> "build_flavor" : "default",
> "build_type" : "rpm",
> "build_hash" : "e5acb99f263322d62d6444ce45a4543dc1c8059a",
> >"build_date" : "2022-02-23T22:20:54.153567231Z",
> >"build_snapshot" : false,
> "\lucene_version" : "8.11.1",
> >"minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
> "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
> },
> "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
> }

Comment: Did you resolve that issue? Having the same one now